# Hide toolbars in RPubs document by default

Tags: html, r

I often publish my RMarkdown documents to RPubs (e.g. http://rpubs.com/cbrnr/R_5), but by default this site shows toolbars at the top and bottom of the page. I can disable these toolbars by clicking on the "Hide Toolbars" button at the bottom right. Is it possible to hide these toolbars by default (e.g. by appending a specific tag to the URL of the site)?

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204900368-Can-I-hide-toolbars-by-default-in-Rpubs-

Comment: Nope. Those toolbars provide an initial bit of info that you've been _graciously_ provided a _super-easy_ and _free_ service by RStudio. If you would rather do the work yourself, then save the knitted HTML to a directory and use github's free pages or Amazon S3 or any other number of solutions that do not do the massive amount of process abstraction for you. RStudio also sells solutions for super-easy publishing without toolbars.

Comment: FWIW, I switched to Quarto, and they also graciously provide a super-easy and free service at https://quartopub.com/ which does not have any toolbars overlaid over the document. So great!